# Find words that only matches two instances of a same character

Tags: regex, linux, unix

Looking for a RegEx that would match words that contains only 2 instance of same character.

So let's say you're looking for words that have only 2 instances of character 's'.

> Test Tests Sam assistant pass lessclose session

So from the above it should only select "Tests" and "pass" as it's the only words that have two instance of 's'

Comment: What about case? Does `Tests` have two t’s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way using `GNU awk`:**

If you are only searching for two lowercase 's' characters:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (gsub(/s/,"s",$i) == 2) print $i }' file.txt
```

If you would like to ignore upper and lower case 's' characters (i.e. match either an 's' or and 'S'), try:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { s_count = gsub(/s/,"s",$i); S_count = gsub(/S/,"S",$i); if (s_count + S_count == 2) print $i } }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Tests
pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
regex='^[^sS]*[sS][^sS]*[sS][^sS]*$'
for word in Test Tests Sam assistant pass
do
  if [[ $word =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo $word
  fi
done;
```

This looks for 2 's' or 'S' characters separated by zero or more characters that aren't 's' or 'S'.

Comment: If your regex engine supports it, you can use `\b` in place of the `^` and `$`.  `\b` matches on word boundaries.

Comment: @WayneConrad Don’t do that, or else apostrophes and hyphens will throw you off.

Comment: that will be due to the bug in the initial version I put up (missing ^ and $ at the start and end).  It should work now following ruakh's edit.

Comment: If you've added the surrounding '^' and '$' in the regex, then I'm not sure what that could be as they both work for me.  Does it work for assistant?

Answer (score 0):

considering the Requirement as not case sensetive

use:

```
echo "Test Tests Sams assistant pass lessclose session" | tr " " "\n" | awk '{FS="[sS]"} {if (NF==3) {print}}'
```

output:

```
Tests
Sams
pass
```

otherwise use:

```
echo "Test Tests Sams assistant pass lessclose session" | tr " " "\n" | awk '{FS="[s]"} {if (NF==3) {print}}'
```

output:

```
Tests
pass
```